# When to set autoresizing mask?

Tags: uiview, autoresizingmask

I have a UIView whose frame I set to (0,60,768,944).

I find that if I set the autoresizing mask prior to adding it to another view, it fails to autoresize.

If I set it after the addition to the superview, that autoresizing works, but when the view shows up, it is - for some reason - has the dimensions 1536x1948.

So neither order is really working for me.

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance,

Sam

Comment: This would be easier to diagnose if you added some code you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that the right place to set the autoresizing mask is in viewDidAppear. By then (and only by then), all of the views have their final sizes.